# Calculate exponential value of a record

Tags: awk

I need to calculate and print the exponential value of records of field `$2` after multiplying by a factor of -0.05.

The data looks like this:

```
101   205   560  
101   200   530  
107   160   480  
110   95    600
```

I need the output to look like this:

```
101 205  560   0.000035  
101 200  530   0.000045   
107 160  480   0.00033    
110 95   600   0.00865
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$ awk '{ print $0, sprintf("%f", exp($2 * -0.05)) }' infile
101 205 560 0.000035
101 200 530 0.000045
107 160 480 0.000335
110 95 600 0.008652
```

This just prints the whole line `$0`, followed by the exponential of the second field multiplied by -0.05. The `sprintf` formatting makes sure that the result is not printed in scientific notation (which would happen otherwise).

If the input data is tab separated and you need tabs in the output as well, you have to set the output field separator first:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} { print $0, sprintf("%f", exp($2 * -0.05)) }' infile
101     205     560     0.000035
101     200     530     0.000045
107     160     480     0.000335
110     95      600     0.008652
```